# MQ EOL Data conversion

Tags: data-structures, ibm-mq, ibm-midrange, zos, cics

we are sending data trough MQ from a z/OS/CICS system to an AS400.

Original encoding of the message is CCSID 500 with a MQSTR Format. The client application is getting the message with the CONVERT option and CCSID 819.

Data is almost converted correctly except for the end of line caracter. Any idea?
The z/OS is sending 0D (CR) as end of line caracter. If they had 0D+0A (CR+LF), CCSID automatically change from 500 to 437, and the end of line still ain't right on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a problem with the CCSID of the queue manager not being set correctly and the wrong conversion table used.

Answer (score 1):

Have already you tried only "0A" (LF)? Have you tried without an expliciet CONVERT? We've never had any issues with this part of the conversion and our machine talks with windows, AIX,  Linux and so. Almost all the time we do rely on automatic conversions.

Also, you may want to check the USER of your job that picks the MQ message from the Queue. Most of the time the USER uses the system attributes (as defined in the appropriate SYSVAL). Maybe this userprofile has been configured very specific and different from the SYSVAL which stops the iSeries in doing the correct automatic conversion.

As a simple test, FTP your data to the iSeries. That will also force an automatic conversion that uses the system tables (WRKTBL). That may show an error in that configuration.